# Нужно ли выделять запятыми словосочетание "при необходимости"?

Tags: пунктуация

Восстановление работоспособности осуществляется проведением обратных промывок и() при необходимости() химическими очистками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На Ваше усмотрение. Могут ставится, а могут и нет. В данном предложении я бы предпочла поставить. Уж слишком особняком стоит этот оборот. И прекрасно заменяется на "если необходимо".

Comment: Полностью согласен с Ларф. Запятая возможна.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишет Грамма.ру.

> ***Вопрос 6160:    Очень часто в документах, с которыми мне приходится работать, встречается словосочетание "при необходимости". Нужно ли выделять его запятыми и чем оно является в предложении (вводным словосочетанием или обособленным обстоятельством)?
> 1) Наличие(,) при необходимости(,) соответствующих лицензий для участия в работе по созданию...дает право...
> 2) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии и(,) при необходимости(,) размещаются на сайте организации.***

Ответ:   Сочетание "при необходимости" относится к разряду синтаксических единиц, которые, в зависимости от коммуникативных задач говорящего, в предложении могут играть роль или обычного второстепенного члена предложения (обстоятельства), или обособленного оборота (обособленного обстоятельства) со всеми присущими им признаками: смысловой нагрузкой дополнительного сообщения и интонационным (в устном исполнении) и пунктуационным (на письме) выделением. Если "при необходимости" обособлено, то его смысловой план примерно тот же, что и у придаточного предложения «если это необходимо». Второе предложение идеально подходит для упражнения "или так, или так". Если в нем оборот "при необходимости" не выделен, то делаем вывод о том, что оно служит для передачи двух сообщений: 1) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии; 2) (сведения) при необходимости размещаются на сайте организации. В случае обособления сообщений в предложении не два, а три: 1) Сведения о выборе конкретного поставщика отражаются в протоколе комиссии; 2) (сведения) размещаются на сайте организации; 3) делается это в необходимых случаях. Ясно, что обособление подчеркивает это условие  -  при необходимости - и читателю ничего не остается, как разгадать загадку автора, ответив на вопрос, зачем ему это выделение было нужно. Первое предложение комментировать не беремся, потому что не совсем ясно, почему в нем идет речь о лицензиях, которые дают право, а между тем сочетание «при необходимости» весь этот реальный план сводит к нулю…